# Image/bitmap in the Balloon Tooltip

Tags: image, tooltip, balloon, taskbar, popup-balloons

Is it possible to have an image/bitmap(Not an icon) in a Balloon Tooltip that applications show from the Windows taskbar ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to do the same thing a while ago, but after doing some research I found out that the balloon is not designed to have bitmap. You can only have icons in it.

Good luck